# malloc: *** error for object pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: ios, objective-c

My Application getting crashed some times when I run the application

Crash Report

malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9f58d2a000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

At below line of code

```
if( activity == nil)
{
activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];//crashed at this line of code
activity.frame = CGRectMake(25, 25 , 30,30);
[activity setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
[popOverView addSubview:activity];
}
```

Shall I add

```
activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
```

at top of if condition to fix the issue...

Any Suggestions to fix it..where I went wrong..

Comment: r u enabled NSZombie?

Comment: YES...It was crashed at above mentioned line of code...

Comment: just try it into ur device once